# Is it still possible to create a fog effect with stained glass in 1.14.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What I mean by the 'fog effect' is when you placed alternating layers of stained glass on top of each other until it looked like fog. like this picture from google. vvv [image: Fog Effect using stained glass]

Or am I just wrong in assuming this is vanilla Minecraft? Is it a resource pack? or even Optifine?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As far as 1.14.1, seems it still works. This video is How you create it, and people in the comments on some videos recently say it still has the same effect.

Comment: Please add the information from the video to your post.

Answer (score 0):

It also works with just one colour:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Heres the way to do it: 
Select 1 color or glass then make 8 layers of glass and 8 layers of air, alternating between the two. (like the pic above)